# Send user to another webpage and avoid 405 XSS Protection

Tags: javascript, web, flask

I'm trying to filter some urls from a website and display it to the user on my site. When you click the url to the website from my site you'll recieve a 405 error from the website. But if you instead copy & paste the url into your own browser it'll work fine.

Is there a way to send the user from my site to the website without triggering XSS-protection?